# MSBuild syntax for deleting files/directories and reporting what was deleted

Tags: msbuild

Vs2010 .net 4.0 targeted project if that affects the answers at all.

I want to delete the bin and obj directories and output a message for the path of what was deleted.

```
<Target Name="CleanOutputs" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
    <Message Text="Cleaning Outputs" Importance="high"/>
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(OutputPath);obj" RemovedDirectories="@(removed)" />
    <Message Text="Removed: %(removed.FullPath)" Importance="high"/>
    <Message Text=" "/>
    <!--<RemoveDir Directories="obj" />-->
    <MakeDir Condition="!Exists('$(OutputPath)')" Directories="$(OutputPath)" />
</Target>
```

Is what I have, but the Removed: message never shows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax for getting the removed directories isn't right. There is the good one :

```
<Target Name="CleanOutputs" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
    <Message Text="Cleaning Outputs" Importance="high"/>

    <RemoveDir Directories="$(OutputPath);obj">
      <Output TaskParameter="RemovedDirectories" ItemName="removed"/>
    </RemoveDir>
    <Message Text="Removed: %(removed.FullPath)" Importance="high"/>

    <Message Text=" "/>
    <!--<RemoveDir Directories="obj" />-->
    <MakeDir Condition="!Exists('$(OutputPath)')" Directories="$(OutputPath)" />
</Target>
```

Comment: But why does [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xyfz6ddb.aspx) states next: `<RemoveDir Directories="..." RemovedDirectories="..." />` How should we know that to get directories which are successfully deleted you have to use it like you posted. I tried your code and it works, but I don't find msbuild tasks very intuitive and easy to use.